# Requested total number combinations for 1 to 6 using all 6 numbers

Tags: calculus

How many total combinations for numbers 1 to 6 using all 6 numbers

Comment: Each number only once, or are repetitions allowed?

Answer (score 0):

It is $6 !$

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, if **all** 6 numbers are used then there will be 6 digits in the number.

$N = abcxyz$ is the number (respective digits, not multiplied).

There are 6 possibilities for $a$ then 5 possibilities for $b$ then 4 possibilities for $c$......it goes on.

Total number of possibilities assuming no repitition is $6x5x4x3x2x1 = 6! = 720$ total possibilities.